# ASPNETCDN Bootstrap Graphicons not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

We have an issue with bootstrap 3.3.5, Graphicons are not working if using bootstrap css from [ASPNETCDN](http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn#Bootstrap_Releases_on_the_CDN_14)

Below is error message:

`Font from origin 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

This is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/g7jt1tcd/4/

I did search around but still not having relevant information. Can you please give some advice to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a configuration issue with ASPNETCDN. My suggestion is to use a different CDN since you don't have any control over there servers. Here are 2 other CDNs that I would recommend:

- http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/
- https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap

Example:

```
<script>https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css</script>
```

Both CDNs have high availability. I just tested them against jsfiddle and worked without a problem.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/g7jt1tcd/4/

Comment: I was thinking that we can have a work around on that aspnetcdn. Thanks @Jose for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I work with **VS2015, ASP.NET MVC 6 (RC)** and also had problems (error messages to the reference, icons not showed) with the gliphicons in production (where it has worked in VS (development)).
The reason seems to be, that the MS cdn page is down (at least right now and from Switzerland): http://www.websitedown.info/ajax.aspnetcdn.com

Therefore (as temporary workaround), I have changed the external reference in _Layout.cshtml (under environment names="Staging,Production") to "internal" reference:
 from:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

After doing that, it works again.
Update:
If have posted the problem for MS here: [my posting in MS github](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3741#issuecomment-164114063)
It seems as CORS requests are blocked...

Answer (score 0):

Just looked into this and add this as a complementary answer which might help someone who needs a small fix.

With this code

```
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
</environment>
```

I get [image]
 and I can see the glyphicons fail to load.

Adding               `crossorigin="anonymous"`

```
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
</environment>
```

will make the glyphicons to load but it still fails. It just fails less.

I changed to maxcdn who provides CDN for bootstrap css and js.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
          integrity="" 
          crossorigin="anonymous"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
```

Setting integrity attribute fails with "Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource" so workaround is to set it as empty string.